# How do I improve my vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary

Hello guys I wanted some tips on how to improve my vocabulary without sounding too weird. I'd hate to sound like a robot. Do you guys have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to English language learners. This question is probably better directed at http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

**Watch movies**. English movies with original soundtrack (as opposed to English movies with Chinese voices).

That way, you are exposed to the correct pronunciation of words.

It may be helpful to also use the English subtitles / captions.

If you practice with Google, you will sound Google-ish - not what you want :)

NOTE: In the context of this answer, you watch the movies concentrated to learn, not to have fun. It means, you listen carefully to the pronunciation, maybe even try to repeat yourself.